# does spring has some inbuilt factory implementation?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory

I have a class as follows.

```
public class MyClass {


  public void doSomething(){
      //B b = //some how get new instance of B each time when doSomething is called
      //do it now
   }


}
```

Does spring provides something has something inbuilt like this?
OR i will have to create a factory myself which will create and return B each time get method of factory is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, and [documented in the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-method-injection):

> In most application scenarios, most beans in the container are singletons. When a singleton bean needs to collaborate with another singleton bean, or a non-singleton bean needs to collaborate with another non-singleton bean, you typically handle the dependency by defining one bean as a property of the other. A problem arises when the bean lifecycles are different. Suppose singleton bean A needs to use non-singleton (prototype) bean B, perhaps on each method invocation on A. The container only creates the singleton bean A once, and thus only gets one opportunity to set the properties. The container cannot provide bean A with a new instance of bean B every time one is needed.
>
> A solution is to forego some inversion of control. You can make bean A aware of the container by implementing the ApplicationContextAware interface, and by making a getBean("B") call to the container ask for (a typically new) bean B instance every time bean A needs it.

[...]

> Lookup method injection is the ability of the container to override methods on container managed beans, to return the lookup result for another named bean in the container. The lookup typically involves a prototype bean as in the scenario described in the preceding section. The Spring Framework implements this method injection by using bytecode generation from the CGLIB library to generate dynamically a subclass that overrides the method.